# anti-reverse engineering on android apk

Tags: java, android, security, reverse-engineering

I am trying out various way to deter reverse engineering on my apk file.

What are the "Bad Codes" that i can inject into my apk's source code or smali files to prevent attacker from reverse engineering.

I saw some research paper that could make the decompiler crash when the bad code are read.

And what are the methods i can use to throttle the decompiling process and not affect the apk orginal function itself?

Disclaimer: this is just for self learning purposes.
Very new to android development. 
Any recommendations are welcome.

Comment: Just don't.  There's nothing in your app that's that unique, that couldn't be replicated by anyone with enough time.  Just implement proper security on your network endpoints and stop worrying about it.  You'll never receive any ROI on your time doing this.

Answer (score 1):

"some research papers" does not provide the least reference what you are even talking about. just try to de-compile it with [Luyten](https://github.com/deathmarine/Luyten) and see how pointless your approach is. proper obfuscation and moving security-related functionality into native assembly are the most effective methods available, to add timely effort to the reverse engineering. making API calls dependent on code-signature is also quite effective. recently the NSA open-sourced [Ghidra](https://www.ghidra-sre.org/), which might also contain relevant tools to test the effectiveness of preventive methods employed. adding useless complexity ordinary is barely effective, while still trying to keep the code-base maintainable. also rooted devices provide a whole different attack vector - and [SafetyNet](https://developer.android.com/training/safetynet/index.html) is problematic to test (it keeps failing with the pre-release checks on emulators), nevertheless this article still provides a reliable check-list for security features. after all, an Android device in most cases does not feature a vandal-proof housing made from stainless steel.